# Assigning priority based on entity total time

Tags: arena-simulation

I am working on a manufacturing simulation where I have 5 entities C1, c2....C5 with different creation time that follow exponential distribution of 50, 45 ....80 and there are 5 different stations and at each process I want to assign the highest priority to the entity that has been in the system for the longest time?

I have tried using first come, first serve but it doesn't work because entities have different creation time which follow exponential creation time so first come first serve does not prioritize the entity that has been in the system for the longest time.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add a "system_entry_time_a" attribute to each entity. Just after the entity is created, assign TNOW to that attribute.
Then, in your queue element, you can use Rule Expression as system_entry_time_a, and choose LowValueFirst as the ranking criterion.